# Infix to reverse polish notation

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, rpn

I am writing a code to convert infix expression to reverse notation but my program is crashing on executing the file

```
typedef struct stack
 {
   char a[400];
   int top;
 }
 stack;
 stack s;
 void push(char *,int);
 int pop();

 int main()
  {
    char x[400];
    int len,i,y;
    puts("Enter string");
    scanf("%s",x);
    len=strlen(x);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
      {
//considering user is entering only the small alphabets 

      if((x[i])>=97&&x[i]<=122)
      printf("%s",x[i]);

      else
//if encountering the operator then pushing it into stack

      if(x[i]=='/'||x[i]=='*'||x[i]=='+'||x[i]=='-')
        {
        push(x,i);
        }

      else if(x[i]=='(')
      continue;
//When encountering the ')' then popping the operator

      else
        {
        y=pop();
        printf("%c",y);
        }
    }

  return 0;
 }
```

Passing array and its size as argument

```
void push(char *x,int i)
{
  stack s;
  s.top++;
  s.a[s.top]=x[i];
}
```

Returning the popped operator on finding out the ")"

```
int pop()
 {
   stack s;
   int temp;
   temp=s.a[s.top];
   s.top--;
   return temp;
 }
```

Comment: Where does it crash?

Comment: on entering the input expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
printf("%s",x[i]);
```

is wrong. What you want is

```
printf("%c",x[i]);
```

AS per the `C11` standard, chapter `7.21.6.1`, `%s` format specifier

> If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a ***pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type***. ...

but here `x[i]` is of type `char`.

Also, from paragraph 9,

> If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So, your code  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Next, for both the functions, `push()` and `pop()`, you're defining a local variable `stack s`; which is created on each call to those functions and destroyed upon finishing execution. You may want to use the gloabl variable instead. Remove the local variables, they are not needed.

Also, for both the functions, you're using `s.top` value as the index of `s.a` array but without any boundary check on the same. You should put a check on the array index value for stack full case (`push()`) and stack empty case (`pop()`) before using `s.top` value as index. The increment and decrement of the `s.top` should also be placed under the check.

---

EDIT:

For the logical part, after parsing all the inputs, you should chcek if there is any element left on the stack to be popped or not. You should *print* the stack containts untill the stack becomes empty to get the *complete* notation. Check my comment below for the idea of a pseudocode.

---

Note: As per `C` standard, `int main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: Now it is printing only the first alphabet and then crashing

Comment: yes now it is working but there is logical error in it ,the operators which are not the part of the braces are not printing in error like (a+b)*(c+d) is printing ab+cd+

Comment: and about the removing local variable part do local variable have more precedence than the global variables?

Comment: @LEONARDO Yes, local variables always _shadow out_ the global variables.

Comment: @LEONARDO and for the logical part, after you finished parsing _all_ the inputs, you should check whether there is anything left on the stack or not. like in pseudocode, `while (s.top !=0) { y = pop(); printf("%c", y) ; }`. Try this and let us know the result.

Comment: Yes now it is working and i don't have to check the order of precedence for it